# PHP 5.3 non empty string ternary

Tags: php, wordpress

wordpress and PHP 5.3. In a short code with parameters [getsomething header_text='Hello World'] in my php code

```
extract( shortcode_atts( array (

    'posts_per_page' => 6,
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'post_type' => 'insights',
    'category_name' => '',
    'author_name' => '',
    'header_text' => ''

), $atts ) );
```

but this isn't working as I would expect. It always chooses header_text which is an empty string if not provided. What am I missing?

```
$output = '<section class="card-lists"><h3>' . $header_text ?: $post_type . '</h3>';
```

Comment: *"What am I missing?"*  => `empty()` to the ternary https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: But in your example, `[getsomething header_text='Hello World'] `, you are providing the `header_text` value? So it will output that text.

Comment: The string concatenation operator has higher precedence than the ternary operator, so you need to put parens around `($header_text ?: $post_type)`.

Comment: Also, as I'm sure you're already aware, PHP 5.3 was EOL over 3 years ago. You might want to seriously consider upgrading :)

Comment: If I was a developer looking at that line left by a predecessor, I'd have rude thoughts about him.  Don't be so cute -- it will cause someone in the future a headache.

Comment: Why not just make `$post_type` the default in the `shortcode_atts()` function?

Comment: @JakeParis this was the original design and the ask was to make it user configurable text.

Comment: @fubar I agree completely. I dont have the rights to upgrade it tho. I was just asked to help out with the site

Comment: @AlexHowansky Thanks. I went with your solution and I got the behavior I was looking for. :thumbsup:

Answer (score 0):

Try change

```
$header_text ?: $post_type
```

to

```
(empty($header_text)?$post_type:$header_text)
```